# Is the SAP Cloud SDK also able to simplify connecting to non S/4 systems?

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk, s4hana

The virtual data model (VDM) of the SAP Cloud SDK is designed to make connecting to SAP S/4HANA systems on SAP Cloud Platform easier. Is it possible to also use the virtual data model for other downstream services?

Answer (score 0):

The virtual data model of the Cloud SDK allows to also consume other ODataV2 services coming from for example SAP SuccessFactors or SAP ByDesign. You can also use the SDK capabilities to communicate via REST APIs. More details in this can be found [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/03/25/integrate-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-with-open-api/).